# Combine 2 foreach for the result

Tags: foreach

I am using xpath to parse xml file from icecat

the code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('140.xml');
$xml = new DOMXpath($xml);
$hasil = $xml->query('//ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature');
$namafitur = $xml->query('//ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature/Feature/Name');
foreach($namafitur as $value) {
  echo $value->getAttribute('Value'), ": <br>";
}
foreach($hasil as $value) {
  echo $value->getAttribute('Presentation_Value'), ": <br>";
}
```

I would like the result to be combined in one row each

can anyone help me?

Comment: i am able to combine it but how to make it html table with two colums? if the result of the array like this 
[Beeldschermdiagonaal] => 121.9 mm (4.8 ")
[Resolutie] => 720 x 1280 Pixels
[Touchscreen] => Ja
[Orientation sensor] => Ja
[Beeldscherm] => AMOLED
[Beeldscherm, aantal kleuren] => 16.0 M